# Explaining Laravel 5.1 issue with registering event handlers and testing with "expectsEvents"

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, events, laravel-5.1

[Preface: **I resolved my root issue, this question is geared toward understanding why it occurred in the first place**]

I have been debugging a test case where I register an event expectation via `$this->expectsEvents(App\Events\MyTestEvent::class)`. The test kept giving me the following error, even though the event listener's code had run:

> Exception: The following events were not fired:
>   [App\Events\MyTestEvent]

Through lots of trial and error, it seems the problem occurs when using two different methods of registering event handlers (in **EventServiceProvider.php**) at the same time. See **Case 1** below, which is my original code for registering my event handlers. If I move the `auth.login` handler to the `$listen` array (see **Case 2**), my test works and the problem is solved.

**Questions:**

- Am I doing something wrong in **Case 1**? or...
- Is this known / expected behavior? or ...
- Is this a bug in Laravel event handlers?

Thanks for your help and time!

---

**Case 1 (original code, testing expectsEvent() for MyTestEvent fails)**

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\MyTestEvent' => [
            'App\Listeners\TestListener',
        ],
    ];

    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
    {
        parent::boot($events);

        Event::listen('auth.login', function()
        {
            Log::info("Login occurred");
        });
    }
}
```

---

**Case 2 (modified code, expectsEvent() for MyTestEvent succeeds)**

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\MyTestEvent' => [
            'App\Listeners\TestListener',
        ],
        'auth.login' => [
            'App\Listeners\LoginListener',
        ],
    ];

    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
    {
        parent::boot($events);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your test is expecting a different event. Are you perhaps confusing which events you're testing for? This line:

```
$this->expectsEvents(App\Events\MyTestEvent::class);
```

is waiting for the event fired in the `App\Events\MyTestEvent` class. The listener you have associated with that in both Case 1 and Case 2 is `App\Listeners\TestListener`. (It is not clear from the code you provided that `MyTestEvent` ever fires, which would explain the exception you saw.)

However, the event that you're registering listeners for is `auth.login`. In Case 1, the listener is an anonymous function, and in Case 2 the listener is instantiated by the `App\Listeners\LoginListener` class. To test for this, your testing code should look like:

```
$this->expectsEvents('auth.login');
```

Assuming that the `auth.login` event fires, you should NOT expect the listener code to be executed since [the `expectsEvents()` function prevents all handlers for running for the expected event](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#mocking-events).

I still find it odd that in one case `MyTestEvent` appears to fire, and in another it does not, since it doesn't seem to be related to the events you're listening for in either case. Maybe posting the code in your various event and listener classes would clear things up.

Comment: Thanks. My test is supposed to fire+expect an even of class `MyTestEvent`. The registration of the "auth.login" event is what seems to throw off the test behavior. I am not testing **auth.login**, it is merely what appears to be causing my issue. It seems like `expectsEvent` is not working properly in **Case 1** because my handler fires, and then the test case acts as if it never saw the event. My best guess is that something is confusing Laravel resulting in my test case's expectation of `MyTestEvent` not being registered properly.

Comment: Have you tried using the `$events` variable that gets passed in to `boot()` instead of the `Event` facade? i.e. `$events->listen('auth.login', ...)` instead of `Event::listen('auth.login', ...)` The example in the docs do it that way, but I'm not sure why it would make a difference.

Comment: The plot thickens: using `$events` instead of the Facade results in everything working as expected. I wonder why.

Comment: Another test: when you used the facade, did you also have `use Event;` at the top of the file before the class definition? Whereas in earlier versions of Laravel, you didn't have to do anything special to use a facade, I've found in 5.1 that you have to explicitly let a class know you'll be using the facade by having a use statement. Not having `use Event;` at the top of the class would result in the facade not being able to access the underlying `DispatcherContract` that gives you access to registered events.